# Run recursion to divide number into largest possible parts until it reaches smallest whole value

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, primes

I need to take a number as input, and continuously run recursion of my function until the number is the smallest prime number the original value can be divided by. I want to divide the value by the smallest value that will return a whole number so that I get the fewest but largest returned numbers.

Example below:

616 / 2 -> 308

308 / 2 -> 154

154 / 2 -> 77

77 / 2 -> ! 38.5

77 / 3 -> ! 25.6

77 / 4 .....

77 / 11 -> 11

The answer is 11 since its the largest whole prime number

My current recursion code:

The methods checkPrime and isWhole are booleans. Check prime returns true if the input value is a prime number, and isWhole returns true is plank length / the value is a whole number.

```
public static int task(int plankLength,int value) {
            if (checkPrime(value) && isWhole(plankLength,value)) {
                int holdNum = plankLength/value;
                value++;
                return task(holdNum,value);
            } else {
                value++;
                return task(plankLength, value);
            }
    }
```

I get stack overflow issues due to infinite recursion, any ideas on how I can increase the divide number, and if the number has no possible dividends left it will just return that number as "plankLength"

Answer (score 0):

Each branch of your `if` calls `task`, so your recursion never terminates; there is no "divide number" that will solve that issue.

Comment: Any idea how I can write it to not loop infinitely? that's really my problem right now.

Comment: First off, you need a *base case*: under what conditions do you know what to return *without* making a recursive call?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understood your assignment but by the example you proposed I arrived to this solution using a while loop.

```
public static int task(int num) {

    int div = 2;
    while ( !isPrime(num)) {
        if(isWhole(num,div))
            num = num / div;
        else
            div++;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: not quite, I managed to get it down but it's complex. For the program you don't constantly divide by 2, you divide by the smallest number that will return a whole number.